# Highlighting words with Javascript, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have been working with a basic javascript/PHP chatroom. I want certain words to be highlighted as they appear in the chat stream.

The html output for the chatroom looks like:

```
<div class="chat-container">
  <div class="chat chat-message-111"><strong style="color: #840;">User 1</strong>: What is your favourite animal?</div>
  <div class="chat chat-message-112"><strong style="color: #840;">User 2</strong>: I vote for #dog. </div>
  <div class="chat chat-message-113"><strong style="color: #840;">User 3</strong>: I have a #cat!</div>
</div>
```

I have found one Javascript solution that is actually what I'm looking for (please see https://jsfiddle.net/4ny8adpg/2/ for a working example). But when I try to use it with the chatroom, it won't highlight any text in the "Chat-Container" div.

Will it not work because the contents of the chatroom is an output of the PHP/Javascript and not just HTML like in the jsfiddle example? Or maybe I am missing something obvious.

Any help or advise would seriously be appreciated.

EDIT (to show code and provide more information):

The chatroom is actually a wordpress plugin, it is made up of a PHP file and a Javascript file:

Javascript:

```
var last_update_received = 0;
function chatroom_check_updates() {
    jQuery.post(
        ajaxurl,
        {
            action: 'check_updates',
            chatroom_slug: chatroom_slug,
            last_update_id: last_update_id
        },
        function (response) {
            chats = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
            if ( chats !== null ) {
                for ( i = 0; i < chats.length; i++ ) {
                    if ( jQuery('div.chat-container div.chat-message-'+chats[i].id).length )
                        continue;
                    jQuery('div.chat-container').html( jQuery('div.chat-container').html() + chatroom_strip_slashes(chats[i].html) );
                    last_update_id = chats[i].id;
                    jQuery('div.chat-container').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('div.chat-container')[0].scrollHeight - jQuery('div.chat-container').height() }, 100);
                }
            }
        }
    );
    setTimeout( "chatroom_check_updates()", 1000 );
}

function chatroom_strip_slashes(str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/\\(.?)/g, function (s, n1) {
        switch (n1) {
        case '\\':
            return '\\';
        case '0':
            return '\u0000';
        case '':
            return '';
        default:
            return n1;
        }
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    last_update_id = 0;
    chatroom_check_updates();
    jQuery( 'textarea.chat-text-entry' ).keypress( function( event ) {
        if ( event.charCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 13 ) {
            chatroom_send_message();
            return false;
        }
    });
});

function chatroom_send_message() {
    message = jQuery( 'textarea.chat-text-entry' ).val();
    jQuery( 'textarea.chat-text-entry' ).val('');
    jQuery.post(
        ajaxurl,
        {
            action: 'send_message',
            chatroom_slug: chatroom_slug,
            message: message
        },
        function (response) {
        }
    );

}
```

PHP:

```
Class Chatroom {
    function __construct() {
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'activation_hook' ) );
        register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'deactivation_hook' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_types' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'maybe_create_chatroom_log_file' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'define_javascript_variables' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_updates', array( $this, 'ajax_check_updates_handler' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_message', array( $this, 'ajax_send_message_handler' ) );
        add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'the_content_filter' ) );
    }
    function activation_hook() {
        $this->register_post_types();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
    function deactivation_hook() {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
    function register_post_types() {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x( 'Chat Rooms', 'post type general name', 'chatroom' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Chat Room', 'post type singular name', 'chatroom' ),
            'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'chatroom' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No Chat Rooms found', 'chatroom' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Chat Rooms found in Trash', 'chatroom' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => __( 'Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' )
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => null,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title' )
        );
        register_post_type( 'chat-room', $args );
    }
    function enqueue_scripts() {
        global $post;
        if ( $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
            return;
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'chat-room', plugins_url( 'chat-room.js', __FILE__ ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chat-room-styles', plugins_url( 'chat-room.css', __FILE__ ) );
    }
    function maybe_create_chatroom_log_file( $post_id, $post ) {
        if ( empty( $post->post_type ) || $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
            return;
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $log_filename = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' . $post->post_name . '-' . date( 'm-d-y', time() );
        if ( file_exists( $log_filename ) )
            return;
        wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' );
        $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'w' );
        fwrite( $handle, json_encode( array() ) );
        // TODO create warnings if the user can't create a file, and suggest putting FTP creds in wp-config
    }
    function define_javascript_variables() {
        global $post;
        if ( empty( $post->post_type ) || $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
            return; ?>
        <script>
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';
        var chatroom_slug = '<?echo $post->post_name; ?>';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    function ajax_check_updates_handler() {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $_POST['chatroom_slug'] );
        $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
        $messages = json_decode( $contents );
        foreach ( $messages as $key => $message ) {
            if ( $message->id <= $_POST['last_update_id'] )
                unset( $messages[$key] );
        }
        $messages = array_values( $messages );
        echo json_encode( $messages );
        die;
    }
    /**
     * AJAX server-side handler for sending a message.
     *
     * Stores the message in a recent messages file.
     *
     * Clears out cache of any messages older than 10 seconds.
     */
    function ajax_send_message_handler() {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $this->save_message( $_POST['chatroom_slug'], $current_user->id, $_POST['message'] );
        die;
    }
    function save_message( $chatroom_slug, $user_id, $content ) {
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
        if ( ! $user_text_color = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_color', true ) ) {
            // Set random color for each user
            $red = rand( 0, 16 );
            $green = 16 - $red;
            $blue = rand( 0, 16 );
            $user_text_color = '#' . dechex( $red^2 ) . dechex( $green^2 ) . dechex( $blue^2 );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_color', $user_text_color );
        }
        $content = esc_attr( $content );
        // Save the message in recent messages file
        $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug );
        $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
        $messages = json_decode( $contents );
        $last_message_id = 0; // Helps determine the new message's ID
        foreach ( $messages as $key => $message ) {
            if ( time() - $message->time > 10 ) {
                $last_message_id = $message->id;
                unset( $messages[$key] );
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        $messages = array_values( $messages );
        if ( ! empty( $messages ) )
            $last_message_id = end( $messages )->id;
        $new_message_id = $last_message_id + 1;
        $messages[] = array(
            'id' => $new_message_id,
            'time' => time(),
            'sender' => $user_id,
            'contents' => $content,
            'html' => '<div class="chat-message-' . $new_message_id . '"><strong style="color: ' . $user_text_color . ';">' . $user->user_login . '</strong>: ' . $content . '</div>',
        );
        $this->write_log_file( $log_filename, json_encode( $messages ) );
        // Save the message in the daily log
        $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug, date( 'm-d-y', time() ) );
        $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
        $messages = json_decode( $contents );
        $messages[] = array(
            'id' => $new_message_id,
            'time' => time(),
            'sender' => $user_id,
            'contents' => $content,
            'html' => '<div class="chat-message-' . $new_message_id .'"><strong style="color: ' . $user_text_color . ';">' . $user->user_login . '</strong>: ' . $content . '</div>',
        );
        $this->write_log_file( $log_filename, json_encode( $messages ) );
    }
    function write_log_file( $log_filename, $content ) {
        $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'w' );
        fwrite( $handle, $content );
    }
    function get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug, $date = 'recent' ) {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $log_filename = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' . $chatroom_slug . '-' . $date;
        return $log_filename;
    }
    function parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename ) {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'r' );
        $contents = fread( $handle, filesize( $log_filename ) );
        fclose( $handle );
        return $contents;
    }
    function the_content_filter( $content ) {
        global $post;
        if ( $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
            return $content;
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )  {
            ?>You need to be logged in to participate in the chatroom.<?php
            return;
        }
        ?>
        <div class="chat-container">
        </div>
        <textarea class="chat-text-entry"></textarea>
        <?php
        return '';
    }
}
$chatroom = new Chatroom();
```

Example of JSON:

```
[{"id":129,"time":1428340673,"sender":1,"contents":"What is your favourite animal?","html":"<div class=\"chat chat-message-129\"><strong style=\"color: #840;\">User 1<\/strong>: What is your favourite animal?<\/div>"},
{"id":130,"time":1428351683,"sender":2,"contents":"I vote for #dog.","html":"<div class=\"chat chat-message-130\"><strong style=\"color: #840;\">User 2<\/strong>: I vote for #dog.<\/div>"},
{"id":131,"time":1428352376,"sender":3,"contents":"I have a #cat!","html":"<div class=\"chat chat-message-131\"><strong style=\"color: #840;\">User 3<\/strong>: I have a #cat!<\/div>"}]
```

Comment: well do you call the code when you add the chat content to the page??? The code in the fiddle will not magically update the page when you add stuff dynamically.

Comment: Yes, you are probably missing something obvious. Text delivered by PHP/javascript (presumably AJAX) can be processed client-side in any way you choose before or after appending it to the DOM.

Comment: I guess the question is when do you want to highlight the hashtag? As the chat text is passed via PHP or after it appears in the browser with JavaScript or JQuery?

Comment: Yeah, if it's returned through an AJAX call, call that code from the success() callback

Comment: I think the real question is @Drakes question! What do you have so we can talk real solutions instead of just commenting hypothetically on whats there!

Comment: @Drakes code as requested! :)

Comment: @Twisty I do not mind which order, this is just my attempt to reaching a solution, you may have already guessed it's a fairly noobish way of looking at it!

Comment: Hi @TrudgeMoody, I updated my answer for your code. We probably don't need your PHP code in this case, but thanks for posting code - it always helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your highlighting code to run after an AJAX call has returned (when there are new HTML fragments), then try something along these lines:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success : function(data) {              
       ...    

       $('.chat').each(function(){
          var hashtag = $(this).text()
          .replace(/#dog/g, "<span class='dog'>#DOG</span>")
          .replace(/#cat/g, "<span class='cat'>#CAT</span>");
          $(this).html(hashtag);
       });   

    },
    ...
});
```

In your case, call your highlighting code after you have populated all your chat fragments:

```
...
function (response) {
    chats = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
    if ( chats !== null ) {
        for ( i = 0; i < chats.length; i++ ) {
            if ( jQuery('div.chat-container div.chat-message-'+chats[i].id).length )
                continue;
            jQuery('div.chat-container').html( jQuery('div.chat-container').html() + chatroom_strip_slashes(chats[i].html) );
            last_update_id = chats[i].id;
            jQuery('div.chat-container').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('div.chat-container')[0].scrollHeight - jQuery('div.chat-container').height() }, 100);
        }

        // Call highlighting code here
    }
}
...
```

PS You can save time by caching the selector `jQuery('div.chat-container')` as a variable so that jQuery doesn't have to search your HTML each time.

Comment: Thank you @Drakes, I have added the code as instructed but am receiving an error in the console:
If I add the JS code exactly as it is from my JSfiddle to the location as instructed, I receive: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

If I add the JS code from the first part of your answer ( $.ajax({ ) I receive: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined".

My noobness knows no bounds, what am I still doing wrong? :P

Comment: I'll look into this soon for you. Working at the moment. I'm sure we can solve this. Can you update your fiddle and post the new link?

Comment: Seriously, any help is massively appreciated. The link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ny8adpg/3/.

Comment: Hi @TrudgeMoody, I reworked your demo here: http://jsbin.com/juveyaqupo/2/ Please reverse it and look at my comments for you to follow. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Drakes, many apologises for the delayed response! I am just trying the code now and will report back immediately.

Comment: Went in, got it working. Nice site. Seems to be a jQuery naming conflict somehow. The fix was to change $ to jQuery. See updated demo here: http://jsbin.com/geredi/2/edit

Comment: Thank you so much @Drake, it's finally working! It does require some tweaking, as it seems like the <span> tags don't stay put. I.e "#CAT" has a green background at first, but then disappears within a second or two. Very odd, but you've worked enough on this! I won't ask you to do anymore!

Comment: No problem. :) I was going to pop in again and look around, but seems I can't anymore. You can always post another question using your updated code and we can look at it.

Comment: You are a star @Drake, I have posted an updated question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653318/highlighting-words-in-javascript-why-wont-they-stay-highlighted-after-the-pag

Comment: The solution is ridiculously simple. Change .text() to .html() on one line. I wrote an answer.