# Highlighting words in Javascript - Why won't they stay highlighted after the page fully loads?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So this is a question following on from the awesome work @Drakes has done on this question previously: [Highlighting words with Javascript, what am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616790/highlighting-words-with-javascript-what-am-i-missing/29616866?noredirect=1#comment47382084_29616866).

The solution is to highlight words by finding "#cat" or "#dog" and replacing them with

```
<span class='cat'>#CAT</span>
```

or

```
<span class='dog'>#DOG</span>
```

Then we can control the background colour of the span tag with CSS.

This works perfectly, however the background colour only remains for a brief moment before disappearing. Upon a closer look, it seems the span tags are applied correctly and then removed again suddenly.

Here is the actual working example for you to have a look at, plus log in details to run any tests and to view the chat.
[Removed, no longer exists]

Below is the updated code from the previous question that is currently running on the working example.

Once again, any further help is hugely appreciated. Please let me know if you require any additional information!

Javascript:

```
// NOTE: I needed to define these variables to make the demo work
var ajaxurl = "http://ip.jsontest.com/";
var chatroom_slug = "1";
var last_update_id = "1";

var last_update_received = 0;
function chatroom_check_updates() {
    jQuery.post(
        ajaxurl,
        {
            action: 'check_updates',
            chatroom_slug: chatroom_slug,
            last_update_id: last_update_id
        },
        function (response) {


          // NOTE: the response is bad, an exception will be thrown, not NULL
          chats = null;
          try {
            chats = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
          } catch(e) {}

          // NOTE: In this test, I don't know your URL, so I just commented out the bit below
            if (1 || chats !== null ) {
                for ( i = 0; i < chats.length; i++ ) {
                    if ( jQuery('div.chat-container div.chat-message-'+chats[i].id).length )
                        continue;
                    jQuery('div.chat-container').html( jQuery('div.chat-container').html() + chatroom_strip_slashes(chats[i].html) );
                    last_update_id = chats[i].id;
                    jQuery('div.chat-container').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('div.chat-container')[0].scrollHeight - jQuery('div.chat-container').height() }, 100);
                }

              jQuery('.chat').each(function(){
                var hashtag = jQuery(this).text()
                .replace(/#dog/g, "<span class='dog'>#DOG</span>")
                .replace(/#cat/g, "<span class='cat'>#CAT</span>");
                jQuery(this).html(hashtag);
              });
            }
        }
    )
    .error(function(xhr, status, error){
         alert(xhr.responseText);
    });

    // I commented this out just for testing.
     setTimeout( chatroom_check_updates, 1000 );
}

function chatroom_strip_slashes(str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/\\(.?)/g, function (s, n1) {
        switch (n1) {
        case '\\':
            return '\\';
        case '0':
            return '\u0000';
        case '':
            return '';
        default:
            return n1;
        }
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    last_update_id = 0;
    chatroom_check_updates();
    jQuery( 'textarea.chat-text-entry' ).keypress( function( event ) {
        if ( event.charCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 13 ) {
            chatroom_send_message();
            return false;
        }
    });
});

function chatroom_send_message() {
    message = jQuery( 'textarea.chat-text-entry' ).val();
    jQuery( 'textarea.chat-text-entry' ).val('');
    jQuery.post(
        ajaxurl,
        {
            action: 'send_message',
            chatroom_slug: chatroom_slug,
            message: message
        },
        function (response) {
        }
    );

}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Chat Room
Plugin URI: http://webdevstudios.com/support/wordpress-plugins/
Description: Chat Room for WordPress
Author: WebDevStudios.com
Version: 0.1.2
Author URI: http://webdevstudios.com/
License: GPLv2 or later
*/

Class Chatroom {
    function __construct() {
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'activation_hook' ) );
        register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'deactivation_hook' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_types' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'maybe_create_chatroom_log_file' ), 10, 2 );
        add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'define_javascript_variables' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_check_updates', array( $this, 'ajax_check_updates_handler' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_message', array( $this, 'ajax_send_message_handler' ) );
        add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'the_content_filter' ) );
    }

    function activation_hook() {
        $this->register_post_types();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    function deactivation_hook() {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    function register_post_types() {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x( 'Chat Rooms', 'post type general name', 'chatroom' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Chat Room', 'post type singular name', 'chatroom' ),
            'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'book', 'chatroom' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Chat Room', 'chatroom' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'No Chat Rooms found', 'chatroom' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Chat Rooms found in Trash', 'chatroom' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => __( 'Chat Rooms', 'chatroom' )
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => null,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title' )
        );
        register_post_type( 'chat-room', $args );
    }

    function enqueue_scripts() {
        global $post;
        if ( $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
            return;
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'chat-room', plugins_url( 'chat-room.js', __FILE__ ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chat-room-styles', plugins_url( 'chat-room.css', __FILE__ ) );
    }
    function maybe_create_chatroom_log_file( $post_id, $post ) {
        if ( empty( $post->post_type ) || $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
            return;
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $log_filename = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' . $post->post_name . '-' . date( 'm-d-y', time() );
        if ( file_exists( $log_filename ) )
            return;
        wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' );
        $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'w' );

        fwrite( $handle, json_encode( array() ) );

        // TODO create warnings if the user can't create a file, and suggest putting FTP creds in wp-config
    }
    function define_javascript_variables() {
        global $post;
        if ( empty( $post->post_type ) || $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
            return; ?>
        <script>
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>';
        var chatroom_slug = '<?echo $post->post_name; ?>';
        </script>
        <?php

    }
    function ajax_check_updates_handler() {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $_POST['chatroom_slug'] );
        $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
        $messages = json_decode( $contents );
        foreach ( $messages as $key => $message ) {
            if ( $message->id <= $_POST['last_update_id'] )
                unset( $messages[$key] );
        }
        $messages = array_values( $messages );
        echo json_encode( $messages );
        die;
    }

    /**
     * AJAX server-side handler for sending a message.
     *
     * Stores the message in a recent messages file.
     *
     * Clears out cache of any messages older than 10 seconds.
     */
    function ajax_send_message_handler() {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $this->save_message( $_POST['chatroom_slug'], $current_user->id, $_POST['message'] );
        die;
    }

    function save_message( $chatroom_slug, $user_id, $content ) {
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

        if ( ! $user_text_color = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_color', true ) ) {
            // Set random color for each user
            $red = rand( 0, 16 );
            $green = 16 - $red;
            $blue = rand( 0, 16 );
            $user_text_color = '#' . dechex( $red^2 ) . dechex( $green^2 ) . dechex( $blue^2 );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_color', $user_text_color );
        }

        $content = esc_attr( $content );
        // Save the message in recent messages file

        $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug );
        $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
        $messages = json_decode( $contents );
        $last_message_id = 0; // Helps determine the new message's ID
        foreach ( $messages as $key => $message ) {
            if ( time() - $message->time > 100 ) {
                $last_message_id = $message->id;
                unset( $messages[$key] );
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        $messages = array_values( $messages );
        if ( ! empty( $messages ) )
            $last_message_id = end( $messages )->id;
        $new_message_id = $last_message_id + 1;
        $messages[] = array(
            'id' => $new_message_id,
            'time' => time(),
            'sender' => $user_id,
            'contents' => $content,
            'html' => '<div class="chat chat-message-' . $new_message_id . '"><strong style="color: ' . $user_text_color . ';">' . $user->user_login . '</strong>: ' . $content . '</div>',
        );
        $this->write_log_file( $log_filename, json_encode( $messages ) );

        // Save the message in the daily log
        $log_filename = $this->get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug, date( 'm-d-y', time() ) );
        $contents = $this->parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename );
        $messages = json_decode( $contents );
        $messages[] = array(
            'id' => $new_message_id,
            'time' => time(),
            'sender' => $user_id,
            'contents' => $content,
            'html' => '<div class="chat chat-message-' . $new_message_id .'"><strong style="color: ' . $user_text_color . ';">' . $user->user_login . '</strong>: ' . $content . '</div>',
        );
        $this->write_log_file( $log_filename, json_encode( $messages ) );
    }
    function write_log_file( $log_filename, $content ) {
        $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'w' );
        fwrite( $handle, $content );
    }



    function get_log_filename( $chatroom_slug, $date = 'recent' ) {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $log_filename = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/chatter/' . $chatroom_slug . '-' . $date;
        return $log_filename;
    }

    function parse_messages_log_file( $log_filename ) {
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $handle = fopen( $log_filename, 'r' );
        $contents = fread( $handle, filesize( $log_filename ) );
        fclose( $handle );
        return $contents;
    }

    function the_content_filter( $content ) {
        global $post;
        if ( $post->post_type != 'chat-room' )
            return $content;
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )  {
            ?>You need to be logged in to participate in the chatroom.<?php
            return;
        }

        ?>
        <div class="chat-container">
        </div>
        <textarea class="chat-text-entry"></textarea>

        <?php
        return '';
    }

}

$chatroom = new Chatroom();
```

Example HTML output:

```
<div class="chat-container">
<div class="chat chat-message-111"><strong style="color: #840;">User 1</strong>: What is your favourite animal?</div>
<div class="chat chat-message-112"><strong style="color: #840;">User 2</strong>: I vote for #dog. </div>
<div class="chat chat-message-113"><strong style="color: #840;">User 3</strong>: I have a #cat!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are replacing all the text even if there is not a match. So .text() strips the HTML and than it does not find dog or cat and just puts the text in.

```
var hashtag = jQuery(this).text()
            .replace(/#dog/g, "<span class='dog'>#DOG</span>")
            .replace(/#cat/g, "<span class='cat'>#CAT</span>");
jQuery(this).html(hashtag);
```

since you replace #dog with #DOG it will not match since the search is not case insensitive

either make it case insensitive

```
/#dog/gi
```

or only replace the text if there is a change made.

```
var orgText = jQuery(this).text();
var hashtag = orgText
                .replace(/#dog/g, "<span class='dog'>#DOG</span>")
                .replace(/#cat/g, "<span class='cat'>#CAT</span>");
if(orgText!==hashtag) {
    jQuery(this).html(hashtag);
}
```

Note: the way you have it currently written, you are going to blow away the User formatting since you are reading the text.